# Create a final product through CodeBlocks with C Language

Tags: c

I am a newbie programmer (more specifically a student) which use CodeBlocks to many exercises (as much as I can). At the moment I am following this steps to create my own programs (File->New->Project->Console Application). This modality has served to learn C language, but I want create a software which any user could use (for now at Windows). Is it possible create some portable through various computers? I was exploring the another option I have on IDE but I don't understand so much, therefore I am very lost.

I googled about different projects which I can do with language C, but...sincerely, I got even more confused. Therefore, what's the next step, to make a more robust program in C?

Thanks

Comment: Which compiler you use to compile your code makes little difference (so long as it is a reasonably good compiler). CodeBlocks on Windows will use either the native `cl.exe` (VS compiler) or `gcc` (from MinGW) by default. Both are more than capable of compiling any windows program you need. It is the content of your program (and the libraries you link with) that determines whether you have a console app or a windows GUI app. There are many good C or C++ "Windows Desktop Program Tutorials" available (and some not so good) Search `"C++ Windows Desktop Tutorial"`

Answer (score 0):

Make a HelloWorld program.
Run it in codeblocks.
Now go to the folder containing that file. You will find three files there.

```
HelloWorld.c
HelloWorld.o
HelloWorld
```

The last file `HelloWorld` is the executable. You can share it to other windows OS to run it.

EDIT:
[C is a portable language](https://www.log2base2.com/C/basic/introduction-to-c-language.html) so its viable. Do look into `makefile` as you intend to create a program that uses GUI, network etc. (RECOMMENDED)

Or you might want to create platform specific ones. For example, [creating a debian package from your executable](https://www.footfallcam.com/people-counting/knowledge-base/linux-create-a-basic-debian-package-using-dpkg-deb-tool/)

Comment: I found this file inside folder bin->Debug (as type of file: .exe). When executed open the dos window and I can run the program. But I intend create something with menus, buttons and images. Something more beautiful to the user. If you can share me projects examples where use a program C which save data on database and allow the user to interact with them, I will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: @0lkufa52: GUI programming in C is *lot* of work, even with a *good* GUI toolkit, and such code tends to be non-portable.  Code written for the Windows API won’t work on Linux and vice-versa.  C doesn’t have any built-in support for graphics (or networking, or database access, or much else.